# How could I do combine multiple tables to a new one

Tags: java, sql, join

I have mutiple tables , let's say 20. And they have the same scheme as

```
CREATE TABLE index[1-20]
(
[id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[word] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[positions] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
primary key(id,word)
)
```

What I want to do now is to join these tables into one table. Suppose the tables can contains the same words. In this case , we just combine the positions together. otherwise just retain the different words to the new table.

I think that we could use full join. But Is there any good idea to do this in java? How to write the logic ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "we just combine the positions" - do you mean concatenate the two together? I'm not sure I want to know what you're storing in that field! :-)

Comment: which version of sql are you using?

Comment: yes, just simplly concatenate them is OK , It's just text. And I use SQLServer 2012

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do the join in SQL, otherwise you're pulling all the data across the network and into your JVM. Let the database do what it's good at. How you perform the join is largely specific to your database.

But, I would also question the database modelling that's resulted in joining 20 tables together.

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` is not what you need but [`UNION`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29#UNION_operator).

But *why* do you have these tables in the first place?

Comment: Because these tables are created by java program . And each table is very large. And I ran out of the memory of JVM when I just created once. So I divided them as you see now. Thanks

Comment: This sounds like the code to create (fill?) these tables is not very efficient.

Comment: no  , actually what I store into database is an inverted index on millons of text files. The map built is so huge that exceed the memory limitation of JVM . So I just split it.